# Run Scheme one-liner from the command-line

Tags: command-line, scripting, scheme

How can I run a Scheme expression from the command-line using neither a script saved in a file, nor starting the interactive shell?

The equivalent in Python would be: `python -c "print 1+1"`. `scheme (+ 1 1)` just starts the interactive shell and shows the result inside it.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/903968/4957508

Comment: @JeffSchaller: sure, nr.2 . answer selected as best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed `guile` and was able to have it execute code four ways:

### 1

```
$ guile <<< "(+ 1 1)"
GNU Guile 2.0.9
Copyright (C) 1995-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Guile comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `,show w'.
This program is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `,show c' for details.

Enter `,help' for help.
$1 = 2
$
```

### 2

```
$ echo "(+ 1 1)" | guile
GNU Guile 2.0.9
Copyright (C) 1995-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Guile comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `,show w'.
This program is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `,show c' for details.

Enter `,help' for help.
$1 = 2
scheme@(guile-user)>
$
```

### 3

```
$ echo "(+ 1 1)" > guile.script
$ guile < guile.script
GNU Guile 2.0.9
Copyright (C) 1995-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Guile comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `,show w'.
This program is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `,show c' for details.

Enter `,help' for help.
$1 = 2
$
```

### 4

Thanks to [GAD3R](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/153195/gad3r) for this one:

```
$ guile -c "(display (+ 1 1)) (newline)"
2
$
```

In all cases, I'm returned to my original shell prompt (indicated by the bare `$` lines).

Comment: Thanks,  @GAD3R! I've incorporated your addition.